# Why won't ADB recognize my Samsung Fascinate on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, adb, android

I am trying to write some android apps on Mac OSX and then test them on my Samsung Fascinate (Verizon), but ADB will not recognize the phone. I have tried everything from restarting `adb`, to reinstalling the SDK. It works on the linux/windows machine that I have, and I know Mac is recognizing the device, because it shows up in System Information.

Other people posted that EasyTether caused problems for them and I previously used EasyTether, but I removed every trace of EasyTether from my machine so that should not be the problem.

I also recently restored the phone to stock through Odin so the problem is definitely not on my phone. If anything, it is a Mac problem.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Ask I'm searching for answers, I switched out my cable for a new cable and it appears to work for about 15 minutes. Maybe its a cable issue/usb port issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  What fixed it for me was going in to the USB connection option after it registers on the phone side and changing to USB Mass Storage mode.  This was counter-intuitive since PC Mode is supposed to be for debugging, but on the Mac this caused the device to register with the adb server and I am able to debug my apps; it will not work for me when the connection is set to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and removing EasyTether and then disconnecting/reconnecting solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://androidforums.com/captivate-support-troubleshooting/132329-apple-mac-os-x-drivers-captivate.html) site has some tips (bottompart of the page) which could help you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried switching my cable out like they said. It worked partially, but still didn't solve the problem entirely.

Comment: did you try the SD card or check the drivers?

Comment: It's a mac so it shouldn't have driver issues, and it works with Unix and Windows, so I bet its not a SD card problem. But yes, I did reformat the SD card anyways.